# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 5.5 workbench

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, workbench

when i execute Prueba01 class show error like "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  '='CLIENTE'' at line 1

## ContadorModel

```
package model;
import accesobd.AccesoBD;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class ContadorModel {

    public static String getContador(String nombreTabla) throws Exception {

        Connection cn=AccesoBD.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps= null;
        ResultSet rs= null;
        String contador= null;

        String sql= "Select right(concat(repeat('0', int_contlongitud)," +
                "int_contitem),int_contlongitud) as item from contador" +
                "where vch_conttabla =?";

        ps=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        nombreTabla = nombreTabla.toUpperCase();
        ps.setString(1, nombreTabla);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();

        if(!rs.next()){
            return contador;
        }

        contador = rs.getString("item");

        sql="update contador" + "set int_contitem= int_contitem +1"+
                "where vch_conttabla=?";
        ps=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, nombreTabla);
        ps.executeUpdate();

        rs.close();
        ps.close();

        return contador;
    }//getContador
}//Contador model
```

## Prueba01

I use CounterModel.getContent ("cliente") where I put cliente to get:

**MySQL Workbench**

Select right(concat(repeat('0', int_contlongitud),int_contitem), int_contlongitud) as item from contador
where vch_conttabla ='cliente';
item= 00021

```
package Pruebas;
import model.ContadorModel;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Prueba01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            System.out.println(ContadorModel.getContador("cliente"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Prueba01.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}
}
```

Someone to help me and tell me how to put cliente in CounterModel.getContador (String nombreTabla)

[Table Contador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Mgs.png)

Comment: Print your **actual** query, read it, and you will immediately see what the problem is. Voting to close for typo. Hint: missing space.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the problem.